# Endomorphism Ring Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that $D$ is a division ring and let $M_n(D)$ be the $n\times n$ matrix ring with entries from $D$. $D^n$ is a left module over $M_n(D)$. I want to show that $D$ and End$_{M_n(D)}(D)$ are isomorphic as rings, where the latter is the ring of module endomorphisms.

Let $f: D \rightarrow \text{End}_{M_n(D)}(D^n), f(d)=\lambda_d$ for all $d\in D$, where $\lambda_d$ is the map that sends $x\in D^n$ to $xd$. I have shown that $\lambda_d$ is an endomorphism. To prove that $f$ is an isomorphism, I need first to show that $f$ is a homomorphism, i.e. that $f(d_1+d_2)=f(d_1)+f(d_2)$, and $f(d_1d_2)=f(d_1)f(d_2)$. I have shown the former, but I'm struggling with the latter.

Let $x\in D^n$. I get $\lambda_{d_1d_2}(x)=x(d_1d_2)=\lambda_{d_2} (\lambda_{d_1} (x))$ so that 
$f(d_1d_2)=\lambda_{d_1d_2}=\lambda_{d_2}\lambda_{d_1}=f(d_2)f(d_1)$ which in general is not equal to $f(d_1)f(d_2)$. The map reverses multiplication. Is there any way I can fix this?

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Are you maybe missing the ${}^n$ from $D^n$ in a few places? In any case, the natural isomorphism is with $D^{op}$, the opposite ring of $D$.

Comment: If you want to get $D$ and not $D^{op}$, you need to regard $D^n$ as a *right* $M_n(D)$-module.

Comment: @Olivier I checked through and I don't think I'm missing any powers of $n$, but I'm a bit confused now tbh. So it's true then that $D$ is isomorphic to End$_{M_n(D^{op})}(D^{op})$? I don't understand what "the natural isomorphism" means.

Comment: @Qiaochu The proof I'm doing this for talks about left modules so I don't think I can start using right modules!

Comment: It seems to me you are, you says that $D^n$ has a left module structure over the matrix ring, but then you go on to talk about the endomorphisms of the left module $D$ (instead of $D^n$...).

Comment: Oh ok yeah the endomorphisms are from $D^n$ to $D^n$, my bad, that's now fixed as far as I can tell. I still have a problem though, I don't understand which ring should be put to its opposite ring. The endomorphism ring? $D$? The matrix ring?

Comment: Well after working on this for an hour I'm still completely stuck!

Answer (score 1):

The claim you have is not true in the notation you gave. If you use left modules, i.e. you write $dm$ and left notation, i.e. you write $f(g(x))$ and not $xgf$. In this case you have $End(D^n)\cong D^{op}$. The answer you get requires you to work with left modules and right notation or with right modules and left notation.