# A question regarding primary decomposition of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, primary-decomposition

This question was left as an assignment in my class of commutative algebra but I was not able to completely solve it.

> Prove that $I = (x^2, xy)= (x) \cap (x^2,y) = (x) \cap (x^2,xy,y^n)$ for any $n \geq 1$.

Attempt: I have proved that $I = (x^2, xy)= (x) \cap (x^2,y) $ but I am not able to prove that I also equals $(x) \cap (x^2,xy,y^n)$.

In this case I have proved it that $ ( x) \cap (x^2, xy,y^n) = (x) \cap (x^2 , y^n)$ for any $n\geq 1$ but I am not sure how should I prove that it equals $(x^2, xy)$.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: You can't have proven that $(x) \cap (x^2,xy,y^n)=(x) \cap (x^2,y^n)$ because it is not true if $n>1$. Indeed, $xy \in (x) \cap (x^2,xy,y^n)$ but $xy \notin (x^2,y^n)$ if $n \ge 2$.

Comment: @metalspringpro Ya, I have made a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\geq1$ we have $x^2\in(x)$ and $x^2\in (x^2,xy,y^n)$, hence $x^2\in (x)\cap(x^2,xy,y^n)$.

Similarly, we have $xy\in(x)$ and $xy\in (x^2,xy,y^n)$, hence $xy\in (x)\cap(x^2,xy,y^n)$.

Thus $$I\subseteq (x)\cap (x^2,xy,y^n).\qquad\qquad (1)$$

Conversely $(x^2,xy,y^n)\subseteq (x^2,y)$, so $$(x)\cap(x^2,xy,y^n)\subseteq (x)\cap(x^2,y)=I.\qquad\qquad (2)$$

The last equality here is the one you have already shown.

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get:
$$(x)\cap(x^2,xy,y^n)=I,\qquad\qquad (2)$$
as required.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for helping me. I have asked many other questions in commutative algebra and algebraic geometry which didn't got answers. Can you please help me with them also? I shall be really thankful. I don't have any guidence in real world as I am located in a poorer part of planet.

Comment: @Avenger The next time I feel like browsing through questions to answer, I will start with some of your unanswered ones.

Comment: You have earlier also helped me a lot. Thank you very much!